# KaiOS - Share using WhatsApp

Tags: deep-linking, whatsapp, kaios

I'm trying to develop an app for KaiOS where I want to share *text messages* with WhatsApp.

I tried with [deep-links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking) like:

- `app://whatsapp/send`
- `whatsapp://send`

Both didn't work.

Does anyone know how share content with WhatsApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to send a text message thanks to KaiOS and Whatsapp teams. This is the way to do it :

```js
const phoneNumber = "0123456789"
const urlEncodedMessage = "SentFromKaios"

const sendTextMessageActivity = new MozActivity({
  name: "view",
  data: {
    type: "url",
    url: `https://wa.me/${phoneNumber}?text=${urlEncodedMessage}`
  }
})
```

Comment: The URL looks like the text-message is sent over the internet to Whatsapp public API (https://api.whatsapp.com/). I think you should __mention this "work-arround" in your answer__, because usually sharing via Whatsapp means to communicate with the local Whatsapp client via URI-schemes like `whatsapp:`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [Web Activities API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Web_Activities).

#### Activities defined for WhatsApp

There are two main activities exposed from WhatsApp:

- `share`
- `view`

See WhatsApp's `manifest.webapp`:

```json
  "activities": {
    "share": {
      "href": "/notification.html",
      "filters": {
        "type": [
          "video/*",
          "image/*",
          "text/vcard",
          "text/plain"
        ]
      }
    },
    "view": {
      "href": "/notification.html",
      "filters": {
        "type": "url",
        "url": {
          "required": true,
          "pattern": "^https://(?:chat\\.whatsapp\\.com/(?:invite/)?[0-9A-Za-z]+|wa\\.me/[0-9]+(?:\\?text=.*)?)$",
          "patternFlags": "i",
          "regexp": "^https://(?:chat\\.whatsapp\\.com/(?:invite/)?[0-9A-Za-z]+|wa\\.me/[0-9]+(?:\\?text=.*)?)$"
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

#### Use activities to share

To share a text message using WhatsApp, you could instantiate [`MozActivity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/MozActivity) using the pre-defined activity names.

Something like this should work either from an app or web context.

```js
var pick = new MozActivity({
  name: "share",
  data: {
    type: "text/plain",
    blobs: [ "This is a message to share via WhatsApp" ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the interest for my question and answer. I did managed to do it quite recently and I've just posted the way to do it for the community :)

Comment: I like the re-engineering approach of your elaborate answer. So I suggested an edit to improve structure. Hope you don't mind.