# How to implement deeplinks in KaiOS

Tags: deep-linking, kaios

A user should be able to click on a link like `app:this/is/some/link?with=information` and the desired app opens and does some action.

This question is similar but just the other side to
[KaiOS - Share using WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840271/kaios-share-using-whatsapp). Another application should link to my application.

Is this possible in KaiOS?

Answer (score 1):

Deeplinks do exist on KaiOS 2.5.3 or newer, but there is no documentation on them. For example, this is from the KaiStore app manifest:

```json
"deeplinks": {
    "regex": "^(app://)(kaios-store|kaios-plus)(.kaiostech.com)($|/$|/\\?(apps|postResult)=)",
    "action": "open-deeplink"
},
"activities": {
  "open-deeplink": {
      "href": "./index.html",
      "disposition": "window",
      "filters": {
        "type": "url",
        "url": {
          "required": true,
          "pattern": "(app|rtsp|data):.{1,16384}"
        }
      },
      "returnValue": true
  },
}
```

The `action` under `deeplinks` points to one of the `activities`, which must accept a required URL parameter. An app can then register using [`navigator.mozSetMessageHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Navigator/mozSetMessageHandler) to handle this activity (see B2G's [Web Activities API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Web_Activities)).

That said, there is no way to deep-link to arbitrary apps. Apps must expose [Web Activities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Web_Activities) in their manifest in order to be open-able by other apps.

Comment: What regex tester should I use for it?